# Angular Material subject is not getting called on Material dialog component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

```
this.loadData();

this.navigationService.savePage$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
  this.saveData();
});

this.updateShownFields();
this.navigationService.formFieldsReady$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
  this.updateShownFields();
});
this.navigationService.setCurrentPage('general-certification')
```

this.navigationservice.formFieldsReady$ is not getting called and this is on the ngonInit of modal component.

Comment: Not enough information here. But start with removing all the take(1) operators and see what happens..

Comment: is the modal created? if it is not in the view, it will not go into the subscribe block

Comment: this.navigationService.formFieldsReady$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => {
  this.updateShownFields();
});

This code is called from modal component but don't know why it is not executed.

Comment: @SouritraDasGupta   then how can that be addressed, it really very important issue. can be a job saving type

Comment: @SouritraDasGupta Can u please help in this. at which time do i need to execute the subscribe block.

Comment: There can be many reasons why this is not working, the observable might not have data for instance.maybe it is getting data after you open and close the modal so you never see it. either way, this data flow is not idea. your modal should get data from the parent that opens it